# CodeIgniter less_than and greater_than validation does not work with time

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have picked up an old `CI` project and have migrated to `3.0.6` and most of the things are now stable, except from  validation rules where `less_than` and `greater_than` have been used.

Here is the non validating piece of the rules (other rules work fine):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('start', 'Start time', 'required|less_than[end]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('end', 'End time', 'required|greater_than[start]');
```

Here is how the time dropdowns are generated:

```
echo form_dropdown('start', $start_end_options, $start); 
echo form_dropdown('end', $start_end_options, $end);
```

Here is the html generated:

```
<select name="start">
<option value="00:00:00">00:00<option>
<option value="00:15:00">00:15<option>
<option value="00:30:00">00:30<option>
<option value="00:45:00">00:45<option>
<option value="01:00:00">01:00<option>
...code omitted...
</select>

<select name="end">
<option value="00:00:00">00:00<option>
<option value="00:15:00">00:15<option>
<option value="00:30:00">00:30<option>
<option value="00:45:00">00:45<option>
<option value="01:00:00">01:00<option>
...code omitted...
</select>
```

What could be possibly go wrong in here?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the validation routines (`less_than`, `greater_than`) expect a number or a numeric string. With colons (:) in the value string they are not numeric strings.

If you use timestamps for `value` the validation routines you need will work.

Convert to timestamps with the function `strtotime("time_sting")`.

`strtotime("00:00:00")` returns 1461733200.

Here are the timestamps for the values in your question

```
"00:00:00" = 1461733200
"00:15:00" = 1461734100
"00:30:00" = 1461735000
"00:45:00" = 1461735900
"01:00:00" = 1461736800
```

Used in a `<select>`

```
<select name="start">
  <option value="1461733200">00:00<option>
  <option value="1461734100">00:15<option>
  <option value="1461735000">00:30<option>
  <option value="1461735900">00:45<option>
  <option value="1461736800">01:00<option>
</select>
```

`less_than` and `greater_than` will work with the above.

You could also write your own validation method to handle the `value` strings with colons in them.

```
  public function timestring_less_than($str, $max)
  {
    return strcmp($str, $max) < 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
  }
```

The above will also return `FALSE` if the strings are equal.

A complementary validation method could just as easily be defined.

```
  public function timestring_greater_than($str, $max)
  {
    return strcmp($str, $max) > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, I will try that. However, why it used to work as expected in the older version 2.1?